Return Button in the Console Behaviour
Does anyone know how to run in the PyCharm console with Enter while the cursor is placed anywhere in the line? In Spyder, I could use Shift+Return to run, regardless of where the cursor is. But I can't find this kind of behaviour listed in PyCharm's keymap. It means that I have to make sure the cursor is placed at the end of a line to run, otherwise Return will create a new line.

According to this walkthrough you can run python applications with either of these commands (OS respective):

Alternatively, press Ctrl+Shift+F10 (Windows and Linux) or
Ctrl+Shift+R (macOS).

